# Error al tratar de eliminar un registro en la base de datos desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Hola a todos soy nuevo en la programación, tengo un problema, mi sistema se conecta a `mysql` y carga datos a la base de datos, pero me salta un error al tratar de eliminar, espero me puedan ayudar ya que no veo el error.

```
private void eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int fila = tabladatos.getSelectedRow();
    String valor = tabladatos.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ?";
    if (fila >= 0) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql + (valor));
            ps.setString(1, id.getText());
            ps.setString(2, nombre.getText());
            ps.setString(3, domicilio.getText());
            ps.setString(4, telefono.getText());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            mostrartabla();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos eliminados");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me marca es este:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of
>   parameters, which is 1)

Comment: Que error te lanza al ejecutar tu script?

Comment: que error te muestra?

Comment: El error que me marca es este:   java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Comment: Le estás seteando 4 parámetros pero realmente solo (según tu variable sql) recibes 1. Los parámetros que seteas deben ser igual al número de signos de interrogación que pongas en tu sql.

Answer (score 1):

El numero de parametros a pasar debe ser igual al numero de parametros de la query. En tu caso tu query espera 1 pero le pasas muchos mas.

Simplemente elimina los que no son necesarios.

```
private void eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int fila = tabladatos.getSelectedRow();

    String valor = tabladatos.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();

    String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ?";

    if (fila >= 0) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql + (valor));
            ps.setString(1, id.getText());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            mostrartabla();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos eliminados");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Aparte veo cosas raras en tu codigo:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql + (valor));
```

¿Que sentido tiene valor en esa sentencia?

---

```
String valor = tabladatos.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();
if (fila >= 0) {
```

Aqui compruebas si fila es mayor o igual a cero pero ya la has usado antes por lo que te puede dar error en el getValueAt y el toString de despues.

---

```
ps.setString(1, id.getText());
```

¿De donde sale id?. No esta declarada en el metodo y tengo la impresion de que ese id.getText() es realmente valor.

Comment: El error se arreglo al hacer unas modificaciones, me sale que se elimino el registro aunque al refrescar la base de datos sigue alli

Comment: Eso es posible porque en la query el Id_cliente sea de tipo distinto al de la bbdd y al hacer la comparacion no casen.

Comment: Como puedo hacer que sean iguales, ya que ambos se llaman exactamente iguales

Comment: ¿De que tipo es el campo de la BBDD?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está aquí:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql + (valor));
                ps.setString(1, id.getText());
                ps.setString(2, nombre.getText());
                ps.setString(3, domicilio.getText());
                ps.setString(4, telefono.getText());
```

ya que en tu cadena SQL es la siguiente:

> String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ?";

Como ves, en tu cadena `SQL` solo recibe el parámetro **Id_cliente**, y tu estás enviando el ID, nombre, domicilio y teléfono. Si eliminas todo los parámetros que envías, a excepción del Id_cliente, tu cadena debe de funcionar:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql + (valor));
                ps.setString(1, id.getText());
                ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: El error que me sale  ahora es este: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ''4' at line 1

Comment: no es la misma cadena que mostraste entonces, porque en la cadena que pones en tu ejemplo, es DELETE FROM clientes WHERE.... y la cadena que me estás mostrando ahora tiene un *, que no va en un DELETE, quita el * y debería funcionar, deja tu cadena tal cual como estaba

Comment: "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ?"

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda, ya se soluciono eso pero no me borra en la base de datos lo que elimina el programa como si no se conectara

Comment: ¿cúal es el nuevo error? a lo mejor no se actualiza tu Jtable donde muestras tus datos, revisa que después de borrar, se refresquen los valores del Jtable que se muestran en pantalla

Comment: No sale ningún error me dice dato eliminado, pero al refrescar la base de datos el dato sigue allí

Comment: que hace `ps.executeUpdate` ? puede que ese sea el error, supongo que estás modificando un registro en vez de eliminarlo, si es que `ps.executeUpdate` hace eso que creo que hace.

Comment: Debería actualizar la tabla.

Comment: revísa ese método entonces, ya me quedé sin ideas de tu posible error.